# Using continuous inversion theorem to determine value of integral

Tags: probability, integration, density-function

Given a characteristic function $\varphi(t) = \frac{2-2 \cos t}{t^2} $ and I have to use the inversion theorem to determine the value of this integral: $2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1- \cos t}{\pi t^2}~dt$.

My idea was to use the inversion theorem like this:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}}| \varphi(t)| dt = 2 \pi < \infty $ (Wolfram Alpha) and 
$2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos t}{\pi t^2} ~dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{1-\cos t}{\pi t^2} ~dt$ because cos is an even function.

The inversion theorem says:
"If $\int_{\mathbb{R}}| \varphi(t)| dt < \infty $ then the probability measure $\mu$ has density $f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int e^{-itx} \varphi(t) dt$"

And Wolfram Alpha says that the value of this integral should be 1. 
So I wanted to use the inversion theorem to show that $\frac{1-\cos t}{\pi t^2} $ is a density, hence integrating over $\mathbb{R}$ should imply that the value of the integral is 1.
But how do I do this? Is this idea even correct?

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}\,dt\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt $$ and the value of the last integral *has* to be known to any Calculus or Probability student.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider triangular PDF 
$$
f(x)=(1-|x|)\mathbb 1_{x\in[-1,1]}.
$$
It is very simple to find its CF and get 
$$\tag{1}\label{1}\varphi(t) = \int_{-1}^1 e^{itx}(1-|x|)\,dx=\frac{2-2 \cos t}{t^2}.$$

I suppose that the fact is known that the function $f(t)=(1-|t|)\mathbb 1_{t\in[-1,1]}$ is a characteristic function. It can be proved by [Polya's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Criteria_for_characteristic_functions). This function is absolutely integrable on $\mathbb R$, and the inversion theorem can be applied.

We get the PDF that corresponds to the CF $f(t)=(1-|t|)\mathbb 1_{t\in[-1,1]}$ (compare with (\ref{1})): 
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-itx}f(t)\,dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-1}^1 e^{-itx}(1-|t|)\,dt = \frac{2-2 \cos x}{2\pi x^2}=\frac{1- \cos x}{\pi x^2}.
$$
We proved that the function $\frac{1- \cos x}{\pi x^2}$ is a PDF. So, it  integrates to $1$.

Comment: Is there any other way to prove that the function $f(t) = (1-|t|) \mathbb{1}_{t \in \left[ -1,1\right]}$ is a characteristic function other than using Polya's criterion?

Comment: I think, no. There are only few ways to get that a function is CF: (1) to provide the distribution for this CF - but we cannot do it since we just need to prove that $g(x)$ is a PDF; (2) to express it through some other CF's using closedness of the calss of CF's w.r.t. convex linear combinations or multiplication (or so on) - but this is not the case; (3) to use Bochner (or some other) criterion. The Polya's criterion is just a Bochner criterion. It states positive definiteness of this function.